# How to get CABasicAnimation progress?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation

For `NSAnimation` in developer documentation I found the `-addProgressMark` method. For `CABasicAnimation` I didn't find anything similar.

```
CABasicAnimation * rotateLayer = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
```

When animation progress `rotateLayer` = 50% I want do something...
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use a `NSTimer` to do this.

You can know when the animation starts thanks to the `animationDidStart:` delegate method of `CAAnimation` (of which `CABasicAnimation` inherits from, [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/animationDidStart%3a)).

Since you know how long the animation lasts (you set the duration of the animation), you can do whatever you need once the animation hits 50% of its duration.

My 2 cents :)

Comment: This solution is sort of an hack... the right way should be to Subclass your CALayer and then measure the animation being played in drawInContext method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more elegant approach would be to have two animations.  You either kick them off sequentially via a completion handler on the first, or register them both via CATransaction at the start (with the second half animation delayed), and again use a completion handler on the first to perform your half-way logic.

At least that way your code is focused and localized.