# Constantly update a label with rotation value of an imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

So I am currently making an app where there is a gauge that animates to show a certain value. I would like to have a label that shows the value of the rotation degree as it is updated. Here is the code I have:

```
CABasicAnimation *myRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
myRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
myRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angle * M_PI / 180];
myRotation.duration = duration;
myRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
myRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
myRotation.repeatCount = count;
myRotation.autoreverses = reverse;
if (easeIn == YES & easeOut == YES) {
    myRotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
}else if (easeIn == YES & easeOut == NO) {
    myRotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
}else if (easeIn == NO & easeOut == YES) {
    myRotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
}else {
    myRotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
}
[[self.arrowPicture layer] addAnimation:myRotation forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

arrowPicture is the picture that I am rotating. So basically, I want the label to show the value of the rotation degree of arrowPicture at one given time and this should update as the image view moves. A simple self.arrowPicture.text = angle doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to assign a `NSString` to the `UILabel`. Which type is angle? You can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

Comment: Yes, I have done that and the label only shows the final rotation value after the animation is completed.

Comment: It does not update throughout the animation, which is what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it related to this Question: [How to get CABasicAnimation progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377311/how-to-get-cabasicanimation-progress)

It basically says, you know how long the animation lasts, so you can set a timer which fires as long as the animation is running.